# write file in node js with packed decimals and binary fields (COBOL) and ftp file to zOS

Tags: node.js, comp-3

We have an existing batch job in zOS which runs daily and writes file with Alphanumeric, Packed decimals and binary fields.

Sample Layout
01 TEST-DATA
02 TEST-NAME PIC X(20).
02 TEST-AGE  PIC X(02).
02 TEST-AMT  PIC S9(9)V99 COMP-3.
02 TEST-UID  PIC S9(8) COMP-3.
02 TEST-DATE PIC 9(8) COMP.

Same application is modernized in React/Node Js.
Now a batch job in Node JS also need to write the similar file with Alphanumeric, Packed decimals and binary fields and will be FTP to zOS.

Files produced from Node JS and zOS should be in same format are merged and sent to a legacy application in zOS.

Legacy application is not able to consume files in another way.

How to write a file in Node JS with packed decimals and binary?

Not sure how to get this done